# How to convert ATL::CImage to Gdiplus::Bitmap and back?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, gdi+

I need to rotate an image 90 degrees, and I figured using GDI+ would be a good way to go. However, I'm forced to work with MFC's CImage and I'm not sure how I'd convert it to a Gdiplus::Bitmap object. I'll also need to convert it back to a CImage after rotating it. Any ideas (or suggestions for a better way)? Good performance is important for this.

Comment: GDI+ performance isn't always stellar - you might consider looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Bitmap` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314.aspx) that takes a `HBITMAP` parameter; the CImage class has a type conversion built in to provide the `HBITMAP`. If you're doing the manipulation in-place then the CImage object will be automatically updated but you'll need to let the Bitmap object go out of scope before you use it.